# Editing system-connections/Hotspot file gives authorisation error while connecting Ubuntu Hotspot

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, internet, hot-spot

I have successfully created hotspot in Ubuntu to share my wired internet connection.

Newly formed connection works fine with WPA.

I edited hotspot connection using `nm-connection-editor` command.

When I change the ssid or WPA password and try to connect to hotspot it gives authorisation error. In the same case when I change the security to `none` it works fine.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Also the hotspot config file (location:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot) shows the following..

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=a7ff7e83-72b8-479a-9445-7b2cf9e4dd78
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address=74:DA:38:1A:C0:BD
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
ssid=chetan-desktop

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=Co0zdbbO

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting these specific parameters:

```
[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=YOUR_WIFI_AP_PASSWORD
```

If you still get errors try viewing the log output to see what is failing:

```
sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: thanks a lot @kristopher by setting specific params its working. just one doubt why isnt these params are set implicitly ? is this a bug or any  specific reason behind that ?

Comment: My understanding is that by not setting it multiple methods of authentication are available and one that isn't working or supported is being picked. The implicit settings for these options (pairwise, group, and proto) leave many combinations to be explored and my guess is the connecting device is trying one then getting mad and giving up.